# root finding iteration using for loop and if statement

Tags: python

I'm using python for root finding iteration.

I first defined F(x).

```
def F(x):
    return 0.01-0.4*x+x**2/(1+x**2)
```

Also I defined dFdx.

```
def dFdx(x):
    return -0.4+2*x/((1+x**2)**2)
```

The below is my root finding code

```
def Testing_Root(x, F, dFdx):
    # store the values of x_n in a list, xstore
    # first, make an initial list with an initial guess x_0
    xstore = [x]
    # calculate differences in each iteration and store in a list, difference
    # first, make an empty list
    difference = []
    print('n=0, x[0] =', x)
    for i in range(50):
        x = x - F(x)/dFdx(x)
        xstore.append(x)
    for j in range(50):
        d = xstore[j+1] - xstore[j]
        difference.append(d)
    for k in range(50):
        print('n=', k+1, 'x[', k+1, ']=', xstore[k+1], 'difference is', difference[k])
        for j in range(k, 50):
            if all(abs(difference[j]) < 0.000000000001):
                break
        break 
    return print('so the root is', round(x, 4), 'to 4dp')
```

when I used this root finding function for x=-0.1

```
In [38]: Testing_Root(-0.1, F, dFdx)
n=0, x[0] = -0.1
n= 1 x[ 1 ]= 0.0004950332214986031 difference is 0.10049503322149861
so the root is 0.0268 to 4dp
```

In my function, I wanted to check whether it converge to a root or not. Also, I didn't want to print all the iterations. I wanted it to stop printing the iteration at some point if the difference is less than 0.000000000001 for all k>= the point.  So I used if loop inside the for loop (the 'for k in range(50) : if all(abs(difference[j])<0.0000001): break' part). However, it does't work as I expected. It stopped printing after n=1 but the difference when n=2 is 0.02306141... which is clearly bigger than 0.000000000001. Why does it not work? What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three simple things to fix:

- `all` is designed to work on an *iterable* (think: "on a list"). By putting the `for` loop outside the `all` call you're cheating `all` out of its power. Instead, pass the entire list of interest to `all` and don't loop at all.
- `abs` and `<`, on the other hand, do not work on an iterable! Instead, use Python's powerful *list comprehension* to generate the list with element-by-element operations. The syntax `difference[k:]` means all the elements of `difference` from index `k` to the end.
- You have a stray `break` in your `k` loop, which is breaking the loop after the first iteration, every time.

So your `k` loop should look like this:

```
for k in range(50):
    print('n=', k+1, 'x[', k+1, ']=', xstore[k+1], 'difference is', difference[k])
    if all([abs(n)<0.000000000001 for n in difference[k:]]):
        break
```

Output is:

```
n=0, x[0] = -0.1
n= 1 x[ 1 ]= 0.0004950332214986031 difference is 0.10049503322149861
n= 2 x[ 2 ]= 0.025061418498996398 difference is 0.024566385277497795
n= 3 x[ 3 ]= 0.0267848938218123 difference is 0.001723475322815901
n= 4 x[ 4 ]= 0.02679343238175541 difference is 8.538559943111618e-06
n= 5 x[ 5 ]= 0.026793432591266996 difference is 2.0951158516413493e-10
n= 6 x[ 6 ]= 0.026793432591266996 difference is 0.0
so the root is 0.0268 to 4dp
```